# Dual booting ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.10

I am trying to dual boot ubuntu 18.04.1, but can not seem to get it to work. I have windows 10 installed already, and shrunk the drive to allow 50gb for ubuntu. When I get to the installation type menu it does not give me any options except back and quit. Thank you for any information you can give.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)